# I'd like to swap my eos token using eosio.token with EOS coin

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token, exchange

I am a DAPP Developer in Korea.
I have publish my own token using eosio.token recently.
I love to study eos main network system.
Now I am trying to learn how swap my token with EOS.
So that I was looking for the contract examples or templates  swapping any EOS based token with eos or any other token.
I am wodering that there are the templates or example from system contract or any other sources I can look into.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "swapping"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For example, if I send one TEST token to DAPP, I get one EOS coin. Conversely, if I send one EOS token, I can get one TEST token. 
To exchange EOS coins with a token that I have made at this constant rate.
Is there a contract that meets the conditions I said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokens are simply numbers stored in tables of the smart contract user that issues them.

You could even create a new "EOS" token if you deploy the `eosio.token` contract to a user.

There exists no logic to swap from one token to another; but you could write it given you had some price feed that creates a "value" for each token.

---

If you create a self issued token that gets listed on exchanges and has a value, you could sell it and use the proceeds to purchase EOS or another token, but that isn't really what you are asking .. that's just using a currency exchange with existing markets.

Comment: I would rather have them dynamically exchange using smart contracts than using the existing market. For example, if I send one TEST token to DAPP, I get one EOS coin. Conversely, if I send one EOS token, I can get one TEST token. To exchange EOS coins with a token that I have made at this constant rate. Is there a contract that meets the conditions I said?